# VSTS Data Charges

Tags: azure-devops

Do you get charged per GB for egress traffic out of VSTS?

Say you have a 5gb repository, and 10 developers and they all downloaded the repo; are there limits we will hit and be charged for?

I cannot find any documentation on the VSTS site for traffic or storage quotients.

Many thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are no extra azure costs when cloning a git repo from VSTS. It is included in the per-user price.

See the additional items [builds load tests cost more](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/calculator/?service=visual-studio-team-services) next to the user costs.

Comment: Thank you very much for the quick answer. It helped us out immensely as we were making quick decisions.